# How to run local shell script on remote server via SSH?

Tags: command-line, ssh

I want to run a local shell script on a remote computer with SSH.  How can I do this?

Comment: see also https://serverfault.com/questions/215756/how-do-i-run-a-local-bash-script-on-remote-machines-via-ssh

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
ssh user@remotehost "bash -s" < local_script.sh
```

`-s` makes bash read from standard input.

**If you need to pass arguments to your script:**

```
ssh user@remotehost "bash -s" -- < local_script.sh "your_arg" "--aswitch" "avalue"
```

Note the double dash `--` (signifying the end of the command options) and the quotes around the arguments.

Comment: I'll have to remember that. Please let us know if that worked for you, and don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it did.

Comment: You don't need `-s`, and you only need `bash` if you really want to force using `bash`. Usually you can simply `ssh user@remotehost < local_script.sh`

Comment: what if local script has operands?

Comment: I have a script that needs arguments eg "sh setup.sh arg1 arg2 arg3" how to execute it

Answer (score 5):

phoibos answer is the working for me.

```
ssh user@remotehost "bash -s" < local_script.sh
```

But you have to be sure that your script explicitly call exit or you will stay logged to the remote server after the script execution.

To be short, do not forget to put this at the end of `local_script.sh`:

```
exit 0
```