# How to run same script on multiples servers

Tags: server, bash, scripts, ssh, automation

I have some scripts that run some commands and send results to my email. I want to run the same script on multiple servers. How can I do that? I know there is an option "ssh". But I'm not quite sure how to use it in the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

text=""
correct=0
error=0

for DEV in eth0 eth1 eth2;
do
  if /sbin/ethtool $DEV | grep -q "Link detected: yes"; then
        #text=$text"$DEV: The Link is up and online on $(hostname) as on $(date)\n"
    correct=$(($correct+1))
  else
    text=$text"$DEV: Link Detected = NO, Please check\n"
    error=$(($error+1))
  fi
done
echo -e $text | mail -s "Alert: $error interface are down in $(hostname)" example.gmail.com
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run local shell script on remote server via SSH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204065/how-to-run-local-shell-script-on-remote-server-via-ssh)

Comment: No it's not working, I have more than 10 sevrers which the same script should be run on 10+ machines. without asking password

Comment: Are you asking how to put a copy of the script on each machine? Or are you asking how each machine should fetch the script daily from a central sever and run it? Or are you asking how a master control system logs into each server, applies the script to that machine, logs out, and then moves on to the next machine?

Comment: Yeah am asking about how each machine should fetch the script daily from a central servers and run it?